# Can't find variable atob React Native+Firebase Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have this post screen where I can pick an image from the camera roll and type a text and I want it to be saved in `Firebase`.
Here is my code in `fire.js`

```
 addPost = async({text,localUri}) => {
    const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri)

    return new Promise((res,rej) => {
        this.firestore.collection("posts").add({
            text,
            uid: this.uid,
            timestamp:this.timestamp,
            image: remoteUri
        })
        .then(ref => {
            res(ref)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            rej(error)
        })
    })
}

uploadPhotoAsync = async uri => {
    const path =  `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}.jpg`

    return new Promise(async (res,rej) => {
        const response = await fetch(uri)
        const file = await response.blob()

        let upload = firebase.storage().ref(path).put(file)

        upload.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,snapshot => {},
        err => {
            rej(err)
        },
        async () => {
            const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
            res(url)
        }
        )
    })
}
```

And here is my `postscreen.js` screen where I'm getting the error `can't find variable atob`,

please suggest me a solution.

```
handlePost = () => {
 Fire.shared.addPost({text:this.state.text.trim(),
  localUri:this.state.image })
   .then(ref => {
    this.setState({text:"",image:undefined})
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
     }).catch(error => {
       alert(error)
     })
   }



 pickImage = async () => {
     let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
       mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
       allowsEditing:true,
       aspect:[4,3]
     })

 if(!result.cancelled) {
   this.setState({image: result.uri})
 }
```

}

By the way, I can see the image is saved in `Firestore` storage but I can't see the text and photo in the `Firestore` database

Comment: You are using this `atob ` somewhere and you didn't define it before use.

Comment: I'm not I don't even know what atob is actually

Comment: but the error is not in the snippets you shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in some versions of `firebase`.

A workaround is to import base64 in the `app.js` and define it in case it's not defined.

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'

if (!global.btoa) { global.btoa = encode }
if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }
```